# AngularJS can't find components when using IIFEs

Tags: angularjs, django

The angularjs style guide recommends using [IIFEs](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#iife) to wrap angular components. However when I try to wrap mine as per the example, I run into the problem of them being "hidden" from angularjs and it is unable to load them

### page.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="my-module.js" %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="my-module-controller.js" %}"></script>

<div ng-app="my.app" ng-controller="MyAppController">
     {{ somevar }}
</div>
```

### my-app.js

```
(function() {
'use strict';

    angular
        .module('my.app', []);
});
```

### my-app-controller.js

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('my.app')
        .controller('MyAppController', MyAppController);

    function MyAppController() {
        ....
    }
});
```

This results in the error:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module my.app due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'my.app' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

If I remove the IIFE on the module declaration so I'm left with the following:

```
'use strict';

angular
    .module('my.app', []);
```

It works, to the extent that the next error is:

```
Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'MyAppController' is not a function, got undefined
```

If I remove the IIEF from the controller definition, everything works as expected.

This is obviously a stripped down example, in the real project I am serving this page from a Django server, though I can't tell if that's relevant or not.

Comment: Those are not IIFE's. You are not invoking the function. End with }()); or })();

Comment: What a thing to miss, works perfectly now. Post as an answer and I'll tick accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are not IIFE's. You are not invoking the function. End with `}()); or })();`

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('my.app')
        .controller('MyAppController', MyAppController);

    function MyAppController() {
        ....
    }
})();
```